Is the map $G^g/G \to \operatorname{Bun}_G X$ locally an isomorphism in good cases?
$\DeclareMathOperator\Bun{Bun}$Suppose you have a closed Riemann surface $X$ constructed by cutting out $2g$ holes into a sphere and sewing pairs of holes together. Given elements $g_1, \dotsc g_{g}$ of a complex reductive group $G$, one can construct a holomorphic $G$-bundle on $X$ by starting with the trivial bundle on the sphere and twisting by these elements when sewing the bundle together. This gives a map $G^g / G\to \Bun_G X$, where the quotient is by the adjoint action.
Is this map a local isomorphism at the points of $G^g$ whose image in $\Bun_G X$ is stable? This is true whenever $G$ is abelian and true whenever the elements $g_i$ are unitary. There would be a failure in genus one, but it's never stable.

What's the argument in the $g_i$ unitary case?

Deformations which don't affect the bundle structure give holomorphic one-forms whose integrals around the $g$ sewing cycles vanish (due to Riemann-Hilbert, basically). The integral over $X$ of the trace of the wedge of the one-form and its complex conjugate must both be zero (since it's inside a isotropic subspace) and positive imaginary (due to being a wedge against complex conjugate).
